# Refreshing tablespace using RMAN incremental backup from one DB to Other

Tags: oracle, backup, rman

If I have two DB's having same database structure and every schema has its separate tablespace then can I use RMAN to take tablespace level backups and apply them on other DB's tablespace?

Example: say I have DB schema 'scott' which have been assigned tablespace 'scott_ts' (on both databases), I take backup of scott_ts tablespace and restore it on other DB and after that to refresh this schema/tablespace I apply daily incremental level backups on it?

(Please note that I've done some research on other options like data pump, golden gate oracle streams etc. I just specifically want to know whether RMAN would help me in this case or not).

*Oracle Database 10G on Windows Server 2003.*

Answer (score 0):

RMAN is a backup&recovery tool. You can't use it for that purpose. You can use it only as part of "transportable tablespace" process in this context. You can try to use logical standby DB for that purpose but it's little bit overkill.